# How to get only tweets from Snscrape?

Tags: python, web-scraping, twitter

After scraping data from Twitter using Snscrape, I am unable to get only tweets.
Under the column for tweet.sourceLabel, I am getting a mixture of twitter, instagram and foursquare.

```
import snscrape.modules.twitter as sntwitter
keyword = '(COVID OR Corona Vírus)'
maxTweets = 30
tweets = []

for i,tweet in enumerate(sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper(keyword + ' since:2020-01-01 lang:pt').get_items()) :
    if i > maxTweets :
        break
    tweets.append([tweet.date, tweet.id, tweet.content, tweet.user.username, tweet.sourceLabel])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not seeing any other social media other than Twitter for `tweet.sourceLabel`. I have fixed few typos in  your code as well.

```
import snscrape.modules.twitter as sntwitter
keyword = '(COVID OR Corona Vírus)'
maxTweets = 30
tweets = []

for i,tweet in enumerate(sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper(keyword + ' since:2020-01-01 lang:pt').get_items()) :
    if i > maxTweets :
        break
    tweets.append([tweet.sourceLabel])

print(tweets)
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Hi @Kulasangar, thank you! could you advise on how to change the query to search for tweets based on geolocation (x coordinates, y coordinates, radius)?